# Portable SSH server for windows

Tags: windows, ssh

Are there any portable SSH servers for windows? I need a really basic executable + config file I can just drop on machines and run as needed. [TinySSH](https://tinyssh.org/) seems promising, but they don't have any windows builds (yet?).

Most of the software out there comes with some bloated installer that makes a service and then needs to run a GUI to configure everything. If it can be installed with a few commands / batch file that would be OK as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[openssh is finally available for windows](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_openssh_server), since the MS guys did some useful work.

Comment: That looks a bit troublesome to make "portable". I might overwrite some keys on the target machine if I run with the default settings, It seems I need to install it as a service too. Ideally I'd like to get it running without admin privileges. I'll accept the answer if nothing else comes along tho.

Comment: yes, there are multiple definitions of "portable".  But you need always some privileges to to bind privileged ports. Also you can modify `openssh` to use the keys in different then default locations as so the configs.

Comment: Also, if a software isn't designed to run as a service, you need someone to *actually log in and run it*...

Comment: Turns out it looks for the key in the local dir by default and it can be run without installing as a service. Exactly what I'm looking for :)

Comment: @toster-cx Which executable do you run to start the SSH server in portable mode?

Comment: You still need admin rights to open the firewall so it's not truly portable.

Comment: @CJ7 It is not portable in the way that you can run in without admin rights, but portable in the way it works on Linux, BSD and now finally under Windows.

Comment: @toster-cx , did you need to run the 'powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File install-sshd.ps1' installation script?

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez no, just ran sshd. Looks like it isn't looking in the local dir by default anymore. You can still tell it where to look for the config with the `-f` param. Generate it a new key and `%cd%\sshd.exe -f sshd_config_default -h id_rsa`